# Spring boot and location of html pages

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have mess with Spring Boot (REST + security) and location of html pages.
I know that today the rest full service project can be created without webapp folder. So in this way I have the following questions:

1) Where should be located login.html page which is mentioned in spring security configuration `WebSecurityConfig` (`.formLogin().loginPage("/login")`) ?

2) When the link to the page is mentioned in `WebSecurityConfig` (`.formLogin().loginPage("/login")`), should controller for this link be created or spring security has own one?

Would be nice to have link with detail information regaring my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a number of getting started guides for questions exactly like this. There is one on [Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) that describes how to define the configuration and where to put your template files.

Comment: In this tutorial is used templates that should be storeged in src/main/resources/templates/ but there is not any word how I should deal with pages that don't use template.

Comment: If you are sending static content then you put it in `src/main/resources/static`. Details in this Getting Started Guide: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot